# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (z-ax^2-by^2)^n x^2 \chi_{[0,z]}(ax^2+by^2) \, dx \, dy, $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

I want to calculate $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} (z-ax^2-by^2)^n x^2 \chi_{[0,z]}(ax^2+by^2) \, dx \, dy, $$ where $z>0, a>0, b>0$ and $\chi$ is the characteristic function that is one if $(ax^2+by^2) \in [0,z]$ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: hint: use the identity $1+1 = 2$

Comment: hint: this does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $\displaystyle x = \frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{a}}r\cos\theta$ and $\displaystyle y = \frac{\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{b}}r \sin\theta$. Then the above integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 z^n (1-r^2)^n \frac{1}{a}r^2\cos^2\theta . \frac{z}{\sqrt{ab}}r\ dr \ d\theta$$

Now evaluate.

Comment: what happened to b?

Comment: and the point after the $cos^2$?

Comment: ...is just separating the integrand written in $r, \theta$, and the expression for $dx \ dy = r \ dr \ d\theta$.

Comment: and there is no $r$ supposed to occur in the equation defining $y$?

Comment: so in principle $x$ any $y$ could be anything between zero and $z$. But in your parametrization I think, the value of the both variables is bounded by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}$ respectively.

Comment: Apologies, yes, fixed with parameterization $ax^2+by^2=zr^2$ and in fact $dx \ dy=(z/\sqrt{ab}) \ r dr d\theta$